# How to run Built Variant 'release'?

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I want to run the app without clicking on "generate signed apk..."

My project structure is :

[image]

I want to run 'main' sourceSet

I use in Built Variants 'release',

[image]

run,
[image]

But error is:

```
The APK file ...\zastavokNet\build\outputs\apk\zastavokNet-release.apk does not exist on disk.
```

Here is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit-cli:1.8.7'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName  "1.0."
        versionCode 1
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("***\\key.jks")
            storePassword "***"
            keyAlias "***"
            keyPassword "***"
        }


    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'

        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile '/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['/src/main/assets']
        }
        debug {
            manifest.srcFile '/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['/src/debug/res']
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times doing a clean (Build > Clean Project) then rebuilding will fix issues such as this.

If it doesn't, you should also try updating your build tools- 21.1.2 is pretty old. The latest is 23.0.1. While you are at it, check your top-level build.gradle and make sure you are using the latest Gradle plugin version (1.3.1, the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after playing with flavors and splits in my build.gradle. And for me switching to another branch and going back fixed the problem